# array_filter and array_intersect performance improvements on large foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

**EDIT: Thanks to nice_dev for providing an excellent solution below!**

I had to rewrite part of his query for correct results:

From:

```
$tmpmatch['unmatched'] = array_filter($deck['main_deck'],
            function ($val) use (&$tmparray, &$matched) {
              $matched[ $val ] = $matched [$val] ?? 0;
              $matched[ $val ]++;
              return $matched[ $val ] <= $tmparray[ $val ];
            }
        );
```

To:

```
$tmpmatch['unmatched'] = array_filter($deck['main_deck'],
 function ($val) use (&$tmparray) {
  return empty($tmparray[$val]) || !$tmparray[$val]++;
 }
);
```

**Original:**

I'm attempting to compare arrays to get a new array of matched and unmatched items. I have a loop that goes through roughly 55,000 items. The processing of this script can take upwards of 20+ minutes to attempt to complete and I've narrowed it down to both usage of `array_intersect` and `array_filter` within the foreach. Ideally, I need it to complete much faster. If I limit the foreach to 1000 items it still takes upwards of ~3 minutes to complete which is slow for the client-side experience.

If I remove them, the script completes almost immediately. As such, I will include only these relevant pieces in the code below.

I'm using a custom `array_intersect_fixed` function as regular `array_intersect` returned wrong results with duplicate values as per [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php#104063).

Explanations:

`totalidsarray` = An array of numbers such as ['11233', '35353, '3432433', '123323']. Could contain **thousands** of items.

`$deck['main_deck']` = An array of numbers to compare against `$totalidsarray`. Similar structure. Max length is 60 items.

```
foreach($dbdeckarray as $deck){

         $tmparray = $totalidsarray;

        //Get an array of unmatched cards between the deck and the collection
        //Collection = $tmparray
        $tmpmatch['unmatched'] = array_filter($deck['main_deck'],
            function ($val) use (&$tmparray) {
                $key = array_search($val, $tmparray);
                if ( $key === false ) return true;
                unset($tmparray[$key]);
                return false;
            }
        );   

        //Get an array of matched cards between the deck and the collection
        $tmpmatch['matched'] = array_intersect_fixed($deck['main_deck'], $totalidsarray);

        //Push results to matcharray
        $matcharray[] = $tmpmatch;

}

//Built in array_intersect function returns wrong result when input arrays have duplicate values.
function array_intersect_fixed($array1, $array2) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $val) {
        if (($key = array_search($val, $array2, FALSE))!==false) {
            $result[] = $val;
            unset($array2[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

To make matters worse, I have to do 2 further matched/unmatched checks within that same foreach loop against another array `extra_deck`, further increasing processing time.

Is there a more optimized approach I can take to this?

**EDIT: Explanation of what the code needs to achieve.**

The script will retrieve the user's card collection of cards that they own from a card game. This is assigned into `totalidsarray`. It will then query every deck in the database (~55,000) and compare the collection you own against the built deck of cards (`main_deck`). It then attempted to extract all owned cards (`matched`) and all un-owned cards (`unmatched`) into two arrays. Once the full foreach loop is done, the client-side returns a list of each deck alongside the matched cards/unmatched cards of each (with a % match for each).

Comment: The problem is the length of time it takes to complete. I'd like to lower it.

Comment: 55k isn't a lot, so it sounds like there's probably a lot of wasted effort (too much branching or checking something repeatedly), and/or process quagmires. The latter I've had with `in_array()`, which can introduce performance issues at really low numbers (hundreds). So I see `array_search()` in both functions and wonder if there's just too much effort, leaning on this function, and not enough setup (like flipping values as keys, which resolves `in_array()` performance issues by having a reference lookup, which is fast). `json_decode()` is also a code smell here, as others point out.

Comment: I Think one problem is in json_decode(), try with json_decode($deck['main_deck']), true), the default is to decode into an object. So in your code it get converted to an object, then it get casted to an array. You do so twice, just do only once an assign to a var and use it.

Comment: Why is `json_decode($deck['main_deck']` inside your loop (and not even just once, but in two places), why aren't you doing this _once_, before?

Comment: json_decode is now done once outside the loop but performance hasn't improved. Added explanation of what my code is attempting to solve.

Comment: @GenesisBits _It will then query every deck in the database (~55,000)_ Then how many times is the foreach loop running?

Comment: The foreach loop is ran once. The database query pushes all the decks into $dbdeckarray. Closes the database connection, then moves onto the foreach.

Comment: Did you add true to json_decode()? The first part looks more like an array_diff(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php try to change it in $tmpmatch['unmatched'] = array_diff($deck['main_deck'], $tmparray);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of optimizations I can suggest:

- The `array_intersect_fixed` routine you have is quadratic in nature in terms of getting the result, because it is 2 nested loops under the hood. We can use `array_count_values` to optimize it to work in linear time(which uses a map).
- `json_decode()` doesn't need to be done twice for every deck. If you do it once and use it wherever needed, it should work just fine(unless you make any edits in place which I don't find right now) . It also needs to be decoded to an array and not to an object using the `true` flag.
- For your `array_filter`, the comparison is also quadratic in nature. We will use `array_count_values` again to optimize it and use a `$matched` array. We keep counting the frequency of elements and if any of them surpasses count in `$tmparray`, we return `false`, else, we return `true`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php 

$tmparray = array_count_values($totalidsarray);

foreach($dbdeckarray as $deck){
        $matched = [];        
        $deck['main_deck'] = json_decode($deck['main_deck'], true);
        $tmpmatch['unmatched'] = array_filter($deck['main_deck'],
            function ($val) use (&$tmparray, &$matched) {
              $matched[ $val ] = $matched [$val] ?? 0;
              $matched[ $val ]++;
              return $matched[ $val ] <= $tmparray[ $val ];
            }
        );   

        $tmpmatch['matched'] = array_intersect_fixed($deck['main_deck'], $tmparray);
        $matcharray[] = $tmpmatch;
}

function array_intersect_fixed($array1, $array2) {
    $result = array();
    $matched = [];
    foreach ($array1 as $val) {
        $matched[ $val ] = $matched[ $val ] ?? 0;
        $matched[ $val ]++;
        if (isset($array2[ $val ]) && $matched[ $val ] <= $array2[ $val ]) {
            $result[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Note:** `array_intersect_fixed` expects `$array2` to be in the Hashmap way by default. If you wish to use it elsewhere, make sure to pass `array_count_values` of the array as 2nd parameter or use a third parameter to indicate a flag check otherwise.

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thank you for explaining this. Performance has improved massively and it's loading exceptionally faster now (<1 min as opposed to 20-30+ mins). However, the unmatched results keep returning everything as being unmatched (so a fully array) even when matched will say otherwise. Changing it over to `array_diff($deck['main_deck'], $totalidsarray);` fixes this but as the cost of some of the performance.

Comment: @GenesisBits That's good to hear. I have made updates to my answer. Can you copy as is and check again? It should work for _unmatched_.as well now

Comment: seems to be the same result for unmatched unfortunately where it fills the array with everything (so they are all marked as unmatched).

Comment: After some further testing, it seems like unmatched is returning the exact same result set as matched given the info above

Comment: @GenesisBits Can you share demo link of expected result and my code's output?

Comment: I got it working! Based on the code you provided I rewrote it. I will add it to the OP!

Answer (score 1):

Beside @nice_dev suggestion your code can be simplified.

The unmatched part is an array diff

```
array_diff($deck['main_deck'], $tmparray);
```

The array_intersect_fixed(), if the problem are duplicated value in array, can be avoided by running array_unique() on the array (I guess is $deck['main_deck']) before calling array_intersect()

This will also speed up array_diff() as it will have less array element to compare.